# Distribution Managed Expiration?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

Currently my Distribution Managed expires . Now the question that I have is do I need to revoked it and then create a new one? Im a bit confused because I cannot find that specific Certificate under the create a new certificates. So what do I need to do with it?. I already created a new Distribution certificate. But what know about the  Distribution Managed one?. Also is there a way to automatically update or create a new certificate before its expires?
MY App is written in Flutter .

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of information about certificates can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8). The most important bit:

> Development certificates belong to individuals. In your developer
> account, the computer name is appended to the development certificate
> name (for example, Gita Kumar (Work Mac) where Work Mac is the
> computer name) so you can identify them.
>
> ...
>
> Distribution certificates
> belong to the team but only the Account Holder or Admin role can
> create distribution certificates (if you’re enrolled as an individual,
> you are the Account Holder).

Certificates can't be renewed (at least manually, afaik), you have to create a new one that is then used for new app updates from now on. Afaik, an expired distribution certificate won't prevent anyone from using your app, it just means that you can't export/release new versions.

Steps to create and import a new distribution certificate (check below for a possible faster way):

1. Close Xcode
2. Go to https://developer.apple.com, log in, click on "Account" (top right), then go to "Certificates, IDs & Profiles", which lists all your current certificates.
3. Click on the blue "+" next to the "Certificates" header.
4. On the next page pick "Apple Distribution" (for Xcode 11+) - "Next"
5. Now you have to upload a "Certificate Signing Request" (".certSigningRequest" file), more information and a screenshot can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devbfa00fef7):

   1. Launch Keychain Access located in /Applications/Utilities.
   2. Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.
   3. In the Certificate Assistant dialog, enter an email address in the User Email Address field.
   4. In the Common Name field, enter a name for the key (for example, Gita Kumar Dev Key).
   5. Leave the CA Email Address field empty.
   6. Choose "Saved to disk,” then click Continue.
6. Click "Continue" and download the new certificate (".cer" file).
7. Double-click the file, this automatically opens the Keychain Access app and imports it.
8. Now you can open Xcode again. To check if the import was successfull, go to Xcode - Preferences - Accounts - Select the Apple ID on the left side, then click "Manage Certiciates" in the bottom right. You should now see a new "Apple Distribution" certificate with a creation date of today.

In the same window there's also a "+" button in the bottom left that gives you a list of new certificates you can create. This might be a faster way but I haven't tested it yet.

For an additional check archive your app as usual, then, while exporting (I use "Ad Hoc"), it should show the name and date of the certificate that was used on the very last page.

On the website you can now click on the expired certificate in the list (if it isn't already gone) and "Revoke" it (red button in top right).