# How to regenerate Distribution Managed Certificate in Apple Developer?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I got alert that my cloud distribution managed is expired in 2 weeks.
Done with read some post that it needs to revoke and create a new certificate.

The one expire is cloud managed distribution like image below, But i cant find distribution managed type when create new certificate, it's only showing apple distribution and iOS distribution, Which one should i choose?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue where mine was a week from expiring, when I selected the certificate I saw that there was an option to "manually rotate certificate", which created a new updated version of the certificate in my certificates menu with a new expiry date for 2024.

you will find the "Manually rotate certificate" option under "Actions" when you open your "Distribution Managed" certificate in the certificates menu.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me.

Going back to @Neklas's answer, the **Automatic Certificate Rotation Date** was 3 months ago for me and for no reason, it did not update(Although it should as mentioned by Apple...)

Going to the solution, I followed what @Shane Oosthuizen suggested and pressed **Manually rotate certificate**, which generated another certificate of the same type.

[image: Apple certificates]

[image: Rotation confirmation]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems this certificate type is generated by Xcode when you set Code Signing: Automatic.

When I open it on my dev portal, it shows **Automatic Certificate Rotation Date**. So I think you can ignore it for now.

Here is my current cert list:
[image: my current cert list]

Answer (score 0):

I too have a "Distribution Managed" certificate that expires soon and I simply picked the "Apple Distribution" one, then went through the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73716635/2016165) to create a new one. So far I've not had any problems with it.